# Google chrome developer sign in 5 US fee not working

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I paid fee twice and it is still showing me unpaid state. I can't publish my extension. Any experiences?

As i sad i paid it twice before and it is still not working.

> What else i have to write to get this post published

Comment: Hi Dawid - Stack Overflow can help you with your code. If you have a problem with payments to Google, you should reach out to Google or use one of their forums.

Answer (score 0):

I explored the developer portal help forums and was unable to find useful information, I'm guessing the payment info might take a while to be verified and go through. You can call them at **1-855-836-1987** According to business insider